# How to create a contact form and having it sent to your e-mail?

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I'm currently working on a project; however, I'm in need of a contact form to have the user submit their information and have the information sent to an e-mail. I feel comfortable with HTML and CSS but not php. I'm trying to follow a tutorial online and it's quite difficult to follow. Could anyone please help?

Thanks!

Also, I would love it if it got sent to my `thanks.html` page. As in, when the user submits the form, it will redirect the user to my thanks.html page.

HTML:

```
  <h1 id="contact-us">Let us know something!</h1>
    <form action="contact.php" class="cf">
      <div class="half left cf">
         <input type="text" id="input-fname" placeholder="First Name">
         <input type="text" id="input-lname" placeholder="Last Name">
         <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      <div class="half right cf">
        <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
   </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "asdf@myemail.com";
    $email_subject = "my subject";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['input-fname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['input-lname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['input-email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['input-message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['input-fname']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['input-lname']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['input-email']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['input-message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>



<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: My contact form doesn't work when I submit it. I need it to send the submitted information to an email. I'm thinking this will also redirect to my thanks.html page. `header('Location: thanks.html');`

Comment: Fix your form first. You need to add (example) name="input-fname" to respective inputs. Also add method="POST" to your form tag

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it! Here is the code in case anyone is looking at this and wants to accomplish a contact form like mine.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<h1 id="contact-us">Let us know something!</h1>
     <form action="contact.php" method='post' class="cf">
       <div class="half left cf">
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
       </div>
       <div class="half right cf">
         <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit" name='send'>
    </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "hunter.shaw@cei.edu";
    $email_subject = "D-Tail Doctor Form Info";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['fname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['lname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['fname']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['lname']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}

// redirects them to link below
header('Location: thanks.html');

?>
```